# How to formulate matrix constraint for cost Optmization in PuLP

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp, integer-programming

I am trying to formulate this complex matrix based constraint in PuLP for a cost Optimization Problem:
I have a `vars[(i,j)] for i in TruckTypes for j in Days` as my decision variable which can take only non-negative integer values. I am trying to implement a constraint on number of `active` days.

Now, Since `Days` are denoted as columns, any column which has all zero values is an `inactive` day and all other columns are `active` days. There are 6 columns denoting Monday to Saturday. For Example in the below Matrix :

```
  1 0 0 1 3 0
  0 0 0 1 1 0
  2 0 0 1 0 0
  0 0 0 1 0 0
```

Columns 2,3 and 6 are `inactive` and Columns 1,4 and 5 are `active`. Now, How to formulate a constraint such as `Number of active Days == 3` for this decision variable.

Any Help will be Appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking for a while.. I think I have cracked this one...

1. Create a dummy 1-D binary decision Variable for Active Days. 0- NonActive 1-Active.

> ActiveDays = LpVariable.dicts('activedays', Days,0,1, LpBinary)

2. Create a Dummy very large Constant.

> M=200000

3. Add first Constraint.

> prob += LpSum(m[j] for j in Days) ==3

4. Add Second Constraint

   ```
   for j in Days:

        prob += LpSum(vars[i][j] for i in TruckTypes) <= M*m[j]
   ```